# What SQL command is required for the following problem?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

I'm trying to display all the appointments for the logged in user through using their username which is linked to a PatientNumber which is linked to an appointment. Just wondering what SQL statement would be able to perform this?

My tables are as follows:

**Appointment**

```
APNo    Weekstart   Day APTime  DNo PNo
   1    01-01-2019   M   9:00    1  1
```

**Patient**

```
PNo  FIRSTNAME     LASTNAME  ADDRESS       username
 1     Joe            Bloggs  1 The Road    joe123
```

**User**

```
id    username   password
 1      joe123    *hashedpassword*
```

For a bit more context, this will be through php using a session username

Comment: Most likely you would just need a bunch of joins.  Have you tried anything yet, and can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: ive tried a couple joins but not sure which would be the best option here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Appointment A, Patient P WHERE A.PNo = P.PNo AND P.username = 'theUsernameOfYourUser';
```

And because `A.PNo` and `P.PNo` have the same column name, you could even use a NATURAL JOIN (shorter syntax) :

```sql
SELECT * FROM Appointment NATURAL JOIN Patient WHERE username = 'theUsernameOfYourUser';
```

Comment: any idea why I'm now getting the Error: Unknown column 'joe123' in 'where clause'?

Comment: Show your Query, did you put joe123 between '' ?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENT NATURAL JOIN PATIENT WHERE username = $sessionusername;"

Comment: Try this :
`"SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENT NATURAL JOIN PATIENT WHERE username = '$sessionusername';"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query in php

```php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$sql = "Select u.username, p.FIRSTNAME, a.WeekStart, a.APTime From Patient p,User u,Appointment a
where p.username='$username' AND p.PNo = A.PNo"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this statement:

```
SELECT Appointment.* ,temp.username FROM Appointment,
(SELECT PNo as Pno, username AS username FROM Patient,
User WHERE Patient.username=User.username) AS temp 
WHERE temp.Pno=Appointment.PNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and maybe apply a filter on `Weekstart`:

```
select
  a.*, p.*
from appointment a inner join patient p
on p.pno = a.pno
where p.username = '$username'
and weekstart = ? -- you can remove this if you don't need it.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, afraid this didn't work, could you clarify the reason for "inner join appointment a on a.dno = u.id" please?

Comment: Isn't a.dno the id that links to the user table?

Comment: the username is the link between user and patient, and the pno is the link between patient and appointment

Comment: Do you really save the username inside Patient? What happens if the username is changed? Do you make 2 changes in both tables?

Comment: So you don't need the User table in the joins. See my edited answer.